# Using surfaceview in list view for playing videos

Tags: android, listview, media-player, surfaceview

I have a listview.Each listitem in the listview  contains a surfaceview, an imageview and button. Initially the visibility of the surfaceview will be gone. Only the imageview and the button is visible.

1. Once the user taps on the imageview  or the button the surfaceview made visible the    mediaplayer is initialized and it will start playing the video on the surfaceview.
   When the user scrolls up and down visibilty of the surfaceview changed again(gone).Only one surfaceview made visisble at a time.
2. When the user touches any of the list item it checks whether the any other mediaplayer already exist if it exists it will be released and new mediaplayer is initialized with a new instance of surfaceview.

This works fine. But the problem is

Releasing a already existing media player and initializing new media player takes time(mainly between the methods mediaplayer.prepareasyn() and mediaplayer.start()). 
If tapped on the listitem and slowly remove my hand it works fine... otherwise if it is tapped very fast it doesnt play the video only surfaceview is made visible.

Current Solution

I tried applying a postdelay between these 2 methods it works fine. I wanted to know whether this is the efficient way of doing this. Or is there any other way where i can achieve faster reaction.

Comment: could you share sample code or an example project about how to play videos inside listview?

Comment: @keybee if your app is 4.1 and above you can you texture view without any problem

Comment: Hey @PreethiRao did you solved this ? Can you share some code for the same ?

Comment: @PreethiRao I need help relevant to this topic.?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi yes

Comment: have a look at this question.! @PreethiRao
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43277315/how-to-refresh-view-of-previous-item-row-view-of-recycle-view

Comment: I'm looking for something like this .!

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi i didnt understand your problem clearly. Are you trying to play video in a listview or recycler view ?

Comment: have you seen that question..?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and use the [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) method to delay the operation , meanwhile use a ProgressDialog to show the user you are loading the next video .

Hope thats Help .

Comment: Thats what currently i did.. I wanted know know is there any other efficient way to do this without using the delay method.

Comment: you can try to prepare other videos in the background , even before the user click it .